# proper syntax of promise

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have a service call that returns me a Study object. In this Study object I have a list of cases. Now this works when I do this.

```
$scope.study = StudyService.studies.get({id: $routeParams.studyIdentifier});
```

Basically this will make available the study to my HTML page as the model. Now I want to do something like this, go over the study object and perform operations on its elements(cases)

```
$scope.study = StudyService.studies.get({id: $routeParams.studyIdentifier});
for(var i=0; i< $scope.study.cases.length;i++){
console.log($scope.study.cases[i].id);
}
```

This does not work since the study object is a promise. And when I look inside it using Chrome debugger it shows up as a promise. What's the correct syntax to get this right?

I have tried.

```
$scope.study = StudyService.studies.get({id: $routeParams.studyIdentifier}).
then(function(study){
for(var i=0; i< $scope.study.cases.length;i++){
console.log($scope.study.cases[i].id);
}
});
```

Can someone please point out how to use the promise in the above context? Just cannot seem to be able to get it right at the .then(function(X){return Y}); part

Answer (score 0):

Your second try was close, you just weren't referencing the right data in your `for` loop.  Assuming that `StudyService.studies.get` returns a promise that when it is resolved it returns the `study` data, you could do this:

```
StudyService.studies.get({id: $routeParams.studyIdentifier}).then(function(study) {
    for(var i=0; i< study.cases.length;i++){
        console.log(study.cases[i].id);
    }
});
```

The key is that you have to use the data passed to the `.then` handler because that is the result of the resolved promise operation (presumably an ajax call here).

Since I don't have the doc for `StudyService.studies.get()`, this assumes that it returns the `study` data structure when it resolved the promise.  If it returns something slightly different when resolving the promise, you would have to adjust the syntax of your `for` loop a bit.

If this still gives you trouble, then add a `console.log(study)` inside the `.then` handler and look in the debugger to see what that data structure is exactly so you can see how you want to properly iterate over the cases.

---

Based on your comments, it looks like `StudyService.studies.get()` is returning an object that contains a promise inside it, but the returned object itself isn't a promise.  This is just a guess since I don't have anything I can debug and look at myself, but it looks like maybe if you want to use that promise, you have to reach inside the returned object to get the promise out of it like this:

```
$scope.study = StudyService.studies.get({id: $routeParams.studyIdentifier});
$scope.study.$promise.then(function(study) {
    for(var i=0; i< study.cases.length;i++){
        console.log(study.cases[i].id);
    }
});
```

If you're still getting the same error, then you need to do a `console.log($scope.study.$promise)` to see what that is.  If you're getting a different error, then you probably need to do a `console.log(study)` right before the `for` loop to see what is getting passed in there.  I could probably figure this out in 10 minutes if you could provide a runnable sample that I could look at in the debugger myself.  This way, I just have to guess and you have to try things and report back.  It's a very slow way to problem solve.

Comment: at the line    .then(function(study){ I keep getting TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: No matter what I do, I keep getting undefined is not a function at the .then() line.

Comment: @user3799365 - then `StudyService.studies.get()` must not be returning a promise because any promise has a `.then()` method.  I'd suggest you  do `var p = StudyService.studies.get({id: $routeParams.studyIdentifier});` and `console.log(p)` to examine `p` in the debugger to see what it is and what methods it has.  If it's a promise, then it should have a `.then()` method.

Comment: Here is what I am doing                                     $scope.study = StudyService.studies.get({id: $routeParams.studyIdentifier});
var promise = StudyService.studies.get({id: $routeParams.studyIdentifier});
console.log(promise); The output of the log is                                                                 --->>Resource {$promise: Object, $resolved: false, $get: function, $save: function, $query: function…}
 controller.js:15
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at new <anonymous>

Comment: So it is a promise object. I have no idea what could be wrong here, but any help would be appreciated. And I appreciate your time jfriend00

Comment: @user3799365 - Actually it isn't a promise object.  Perhaps it contains a promise object.  See what I added to my answer.